# Rails 3 public_activity, destroy record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the [public_activity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) gem tracking if a user creates a post.
Is there a way to destroy a public activity record, on deletion of the post, so that in the activities feed it doesn't show something like:

```
A post was deleted.
```

And instead just deletes that particular activity in the activities table

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is what the OP was looking for / may have figured out, but didn't post in a solution.

Quick example scenario:

A user creates a comment, therefore a Public Activity Record (key: comment.create) is created for that comment.

Now, lets say the user deletes his comment.

There is still an activity (key: comment.create) stored in the activities table that relates to the original comment that just got deleted.

To delete that original activity all together when a user deletes their corresponding activity (key: comment.create). Simply do the following.

```
#comments_controller.rb or whatever class you are tracking
def destroy
  @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
  @activity = PublicActivity::Activity.find_by(trackable_id: (params[:id]), trackable_type: controller_path.classify)
  @activity.destroy
  @comment.destroy
end
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I'm getting a undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass, what am i missing ?

Comment: how are you creating the activity? did you implement it based off the rails cast? http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at my question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046076/undefined-method-destroy-on-public-activity

Comment: responded to you question in the comments. Let me know if that works and I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your Post model you can tracked a details 0f deleted post so you can use it when you are displaying a notifications about post deletion.
you can improve your notification "A post was deleted" for example " A post with content XYZ deleted at abc time format"
for example your Post.rb having a field :content so in your Post.rb

```
class Post <  ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Model
tracked :params => {
      :content => proc {|controller, model| (model.content)}   
  }
```

and in your public_activity/post/destroy.html.haml
you can access content `p[:content]`
Or you can reject the activity record with :key => post.destroy 
for that in your notifications controller in action index
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController

```
def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").reject{|activity| (activity.key == "post.destroy" }
```

this will not notify post deletions details in notifications.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Since I don't wish to dump the table and waste  some space, can I just delete that record
I mean is it actually possible?

Comment: you can select a record activity = PublicActivity::Activity.select{|activity|(activity.key == "post.destroy")}
 and delete it in index method and then use the all activity record for notifications am i right?

Comment: I am actually trying to star/unstar a post. And when I unstar a post, I want the activity when I starred to be deleted.
Is it possible?