# Destroying UpVotes on acts_as_votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, public-activity

I have a rails app that is working fine using acts_as_votable. The like button upvotes the post count, and then switches to an un-like button and this down votes the post count.

My issue is, that since I started using the Public Activity gem, I can't find a way to remove likes from the feed. I have used the following loop in the activities index view:

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
    <p>
        <% if activity.trackable %>
            <%= link_to activity.owner.name, activity.owner %>
            <%= render_activity activity %>
        <% end %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

When I delete a comment, the entire line in the activity feed of 'FOO added a comment on BAR' disappears. However, because the acts as votable gem actually creates a downvote rather than destroying the upvote, the line 'FOO liked BAR' still appears and would be subsequently followed by 'FOO unliked BAR'.

Does anybody know how I can locate the upvote by the current_user on a particular post and then destroy it?

Below is my controller code for like and unlike as it stands:

```
def like
  @ink.create_activity :like, owner: current_user
  @ink.upvote_by current_user

  redirect_to :back
end

def unlike
  @ink.downvote_by current_user

  redirect_to :back
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone that stumbles across this in future, thanks to Element119 I was eventually able to pinpoint the current users likes on a particular post with a few variables and arel searches. I then destroyed the pinpointed likes.

```
def like
    @post.create_activity  :like, 
                           owner: current_user,
                           recipient: @post.user
    @post.upvote_by current_user

    redirect_to :back
  end



def unlike
    @post.downvote_by current_user

    @currentUserLikes = PublicActivity::Activity.where(trackable_id: @post.id, owner_id: current_user.id, key: "post.like")
    @currentUserLikes.destroy_all

    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this have been answered but the ideal and easiest answer would be using the official gem method which is **unvote_by** it works for both upvotes and downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you want to do is remove the model's like notification when it is "unliked" - is that correct? All you have to do is find the relevant activity and destroy it. Because Activities are models just like any other, you can do this with `destroy` and/or `destroy_all`.

I'm not quite sure what your public_activity model looks like, so instead of giving a specific example I'll link you to [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/public-activity/3blVGNRGITQ) on the mailing list for the gem, which shows examples of deleting public activity records.

You may also find it useful to delete the record by its `trackable_id` - for example:

```
@activity = PublicActivity::Activity.find_by(trackable_id: (params[:id]), trackable_type: controller_path.classify)
@activity.destroy
```

There's more information about how that works in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18429493/353878).

Comment: I've given you the bounty, because you pointed me in the right direction! I still had to do quite a bit of digging but I eventually managed to sort it! Thanks so much for taking the time to answer this. I will post the final solution to this puzzle as an answer to help anyone in future!